# Firefox inspect: display: ambigous (inline-block in "styles", block in Layout Tab)

Tags: html, css, layout, display

From what I learnt in the "Web Dev simplified youtube tutorial" inline-block is exactly like inline but you can change width & height.

[image]

Ambigous information here, now I don't even know what it really is. Firefox inspect-tools bug or am I missing something?

Comment: share more code, this is not ambiguous but something well defined and it depends on your full code (like the CSS of the parent element for example)

Comment: Yes I just thought it was ambiguous before, but now I know that the defined rules don‘t have to have the same property-values as the actual runtime-property-value of the element

Answer (score -1):

"inline-block is exactly like inline but you can change width & height"

This is how you can *think of it*.

But according to MDN:

inline-block
The element generates a block element box that will be flowed with surrounding content as if it were a single inline box (behaving much like a replaced element would).

Now you probably still wonder why the inspect tools don't show you "display: inline-block". Somehow the browser converts "inline-block" to block. I don't know **why** this is done

why exactly is inline-block not actually a real/static/constant display property?
(I don't find the info on "Precomposed <display-legacy>" on MDN very helpful to answer this.)

### more info on this would be appreciated by more experienced devs.

Comment: An explanation like "only "block" and "inline" are actually display-values that the browser outputs" would be what I expect as an answer (Although this example-answer is definitely not correct!). And to explain why some get "output" by the browser and why some do not.